# Posting from servlet to database is throwing a "column does not exist error". How can I fix and complete this?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am new to java and am trying to add appointments to a table in a database using a servlet. I am able to get the information and display it but I cannot figure out how to properly insert new records into my table. Currently, the error is saying that the column named "first" does not exist. However, it seems to work when I pull the information with the "query" variable.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AppointmentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AppointmentServlet() {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      doGet(request, response);
        System.out.println("doPost method running");

        String first = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String last = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String day = request.getParameter("day");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO \"Reservations\"(\r\n" + 
                "   \"Last\", \"First\", \"Day\")\r\n" + 
                "   VALUES (first, last, day);";
//      String query = "SELECT * FROM \"Reservations\"";


        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/HospitalReservations", "postgres", "coffeeCup");
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database connection successfully.");
            System.out.println("C: " + c);

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            c.commit();


            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                String firstname = rs.getString("first");
                String lastname = rs.getString("last");
                String daytime = rs.getString("day");

                System.out.println("NAME = " + firstname + " " + lastname);
                System.out.println("DAY = " + daytime);
            }


        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.err.print(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Operation done successfully.");


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Appointment Response</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h3> Reservation Made </h3>");
        out.println("<p>" + first + " " + last + " has been added for " + day  + "</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }

}
```

Comment: [Learn to use a PreparedStatement](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)  and your problem will go away

Comment: It looks like your last edit only introduces the solution that gavincook offered in his answer (and that you accepted). Your edit invalidates his answer, and makes your question confusing, because it no longer has your original problem. That is not how Stack Overflow works: you should not fix the problem in the question. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PreparedStatement` when parameters need passed. For example, in your case:

```
    //use ? for parameter placeholder
    String sql = "INSERT INTO \"Reservations\"(\r\n" + 
            "   \"Last\", \"First\", \"Day\")\r\n" + 
            "   VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, last);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, first);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, day);
    preparedStatement.execute();
```

**Note:** The first parameter of `preparedStatement.setXXX` methods called `parameterIndex`, it start with 1. the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...

Comment: Ok that actually helped. The database is not actually updating though. Do you know why that might be? I updated the code. s

Comment: You should commit the transaction after the preparedStatement execute if auto commit feature is disabled.  In your code, `c.commit();` is the code of transaction commit.